# Pyenv – enabling python3.7 command

Tags: python

I've just got a backend repository to launch locally. It uses poetry for the dependencies and has this specified `python = ">=3.7,<3.8"`.

- `python -V` -> Python 2.7.16
- `python3 -V` -> Python 3.8.5
- `which python` -> /usr/local/bin/python
- `which python3` -> /usr/local/bin/python3

I've installed `pyenv` using `brew` and installed `3.7.8` (which is now visible when running `pyenv versions`).

Running `poetry shell` throws me:

```
The currently activated Python version 3.8.5 is not supported by the project (>=3.7,<3.8).
```

And when trying to `poetry env use 3.7.8` it returns:

```
/bin/sh: python3.7: command not found
```

My question is – how can I setup `python3.7` command on my macOS?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like there's no `python3.7` executable linked explicitly by `pyenv` on your path.

You should enable `3.7.8` as the local version for your project by running: `pyenv local 3.7.8` inside the project directory.

You could also tell `poetry` to use it directly by passing `poetry env use` the *full* executable path (not just the version string).

Comment: I've run `pyenv local 3.7.8` in the repo directory (it created `.python-version` file) – didn't help :(

Comment: I've tried adding `eval "$(pyenv init -)"` to my `~/.bash_profile` but I forgot about using `~/.zshrc`. Adding the line there made the command (`python3.7`) work!